# How do I restrict access to edit action and through URL entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a relationship user ("devise") that has many events.

I want to prevent users from editing events that do not belong to them and stop users from accessing the edit action by entering something like `'http://localhost:3000/events/65/edit'` into the browser.

I also want to redirect the user back to the page they were on when clicking on the edit event link.

I tried the following two methods without success:

```
def edit
  if current_user == @event.user_id
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  else
    redirect_to events_path
  end

  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    unless session[:id] == @event.user_id
      redirect_to events_path
      return
    end
  end
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it more readable. Your code isn't valid. The first `edit` is missing its closing `end`.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need this kind of authorization logic in this controller, something like this would be possible:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to events_path, notice: "You cannot edit this event."
  end
end
```

The rescue-block is really optional. If you remove it, the user will get a `404 Not found` error message if she visits the edit URL for an event she didn't create,

If you expect to use authorization other places in your application, I would advise you to look into [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It's a gem that sentralizes rules for authorization and access in an Ability class.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a before filter (it can be used for other actions as well if needed):

```
 before_filter :check_user, :only => [:edit]

 def check_user
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user.id == @event.user_id
       redirect_to (request.referrer || root_path)
       return
    end
 end
```

Comment: I think you should keep setting the @event in the `edit` method. Hiding instance variables in before_filters is a debated practice, but if one should do it, it should happen consistently for all controller actions.

Comment: I am imagining this filter to be used for multiple member actions on the events controller like show. If this is to be done just for `edit` then this whole logic can be moved to the edit action itself.

Comment: The problem is that the method name `check_user` doesn't imply what it does. A separate `find_event` before_filter, and an `authorize_access`  before_filter would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind your first method is fine, but that comparison will always fail. `current_user` is a User object; `@event.user_id` is an integer (or possibly some form of UUID).

You need to either compare a User object to a User object:

```
if current_user == @event.user
```

Or an ID to an ID:

```
if current_user.id == @event.user_id
```